# run test with selenium web driver - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, runtime-error

I tried to figure out how works - selenium web driver.

And tried to run easy program, but caught next error at console:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: selenium/web/driver/Selenium2Example
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: selenium.web.driver.Selenium2Example
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main"
```

and pop-up window with message:

```
Could not find the main class, program will exit
```

I'm using Eclipse Helios under Windows XP.
I attached neded -jars for progect (`selenium-java-2.35.0` + `selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0`).

**Here is code:**

```
public class Selenium2Example {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
        // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface,
        // not the implementation.
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        // And now use this to visit Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        // Alternatively the same thing can be done like this
        // driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");
        // Find the text input element by its name
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        // Enter something to search for
        element.sendKeys("Cheese!");
        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the
        // element
        element.submit();
        // Check the title of the page
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
        // Google's search is rendered dynamically with JavaScript.
        // Wait for the page to load, timeout after 10 seconds
        (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                return d.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith("cheese!");
            }
        });
        // Should see: "cheese! - Google Search"
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
        // Close the browser
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

I can't understand why this couldn't find main class...

Even more it couldn't create executable files `.class` into `bin` folder.

Any suggestion?

- ***Why this exactly happen and how to solve this trouble?***

Comment: Did you set JAVA classpath ?

Comment: Add either selenium stand alone or the selenium-java-2.35.0. Not both. Also if you are using selenium-java-2.35.0 then in the downloaded folder there will be another sub folder which contains all the other required jars. You need to add that as well.

Comment: @HemChe of course I did this.

Comment: @Vinay But why, we need `elenium-standalone` for `WebDriverWait(driver, 10))...` without this import it wouldn't work. We have to use `Thread.sleep(3000);` - and omit this `-jar`..

Comment: @nazar_art you need to add all the jar files present in `libs` folder of selenium java bindings folder to the buildpath.

Comment: @nazar_art This are the core jar files that are required by selenium to function properly. I also said either stand alone or the all the jar from selenium-java-2.35.0. Using stand alone ensures that you don't have to manage multiple jar files and single jar would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Remove selenium stand alone jar and Add **selenium-java-2.33.0-srcs.jar** ,  **selenium-java-2.33.0.jar**  to lib and Run as **java application**

Comment: The OP's own class is the one that can't be found, so merely switching Selenium JARs around won't change anything.